# Unexpected token on render react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code which I expect would display a list of keys and values:

```js
render() {
        let content;

        if (this.props.json != null) {
            content = {
                Object.keys(this.props.json.fields).map(function (key) {
                    return <div>Key: {key}, Value: {this.props.json.fields[key]}</div>;
                })
            }
        } 

        return (
            <div>
                {content}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

However, for some reason i get this error:

Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Which points to the "Object.keys" I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, I've searched the internet and have seen ALOT of examples like this which work

Comment: Remove the curly braces around the `Object.keys` section. I believe you meant to do `content = Object.keys(...`. What you have there is a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're wrapping "Object.keys..." with curly braces, you're declaring the **content** variable as an object. You can declare it without the curly braces, then **content** will be an array, and that should render properly.

```
if (this.props.json != null) {
    content = Object.keys(this.props.json.fields).map(function (key) {
        return <div>Key: {key}, Value: {this.props.json.fields[key]}</div>;
    });
}
```